# delete leading characters before a string in C (concept question)

Tags: c, c-strings, trim, string-literals, function-definition

I’m learning C, dealing with strings and pointers.  An exercise calls for deleting all leading characters (‘X’ in this case) before a string.  The called function must accept a string, i.e. a pointer to a char.  I have found multiple ways of doing this by searching, but I do not understand why the following code does not work...what concept am I missing?

```
     //delete all leading X characters by passing pointer to a string
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     
     void delChar(char* str)
     {
         char* walker; //declare pointer
         walker = str;  //point to beginning of passed string
         
         while(*walker == 'X') walker++; //move pointer past amy leading 'X' 
        
         printf("\nwalker string is now: %s", walker); //prints "Test" as expected
         
         str = walker; //set str pointer to walker
         printf("\nstr string is now: %s", str); //prints "Test" as expected
         
         return;
     }
     
     int main()
     {
         char* myStr = "XXXXXXXXXXXXTest";
         printf("Before function call: %s", myStr); //prints "XXXXXXXXXXXXTest" as expected
        
         delChar(myStr); //pass pointer to the string
         
         printf("\nAfter function call: %s", myStr); //WHY DOES THIS print "XXXXXXXXXXXXTest" ?
         
         return 0;
     }
```

Comment: you have passed the address of the variable and not the variable, so after the return still variable will hold the same address

Comment: Your `main()` defines a string literal... You cannot _delete_ characters from that string as it is _immutable_... You can only find the index of the first character that is not 'X'.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways in which characters can be deleted from a string, and it is not clear which you want.

In C, memory contents cannot be “deleted.” Memory is formed of bytes, and bytes hold values. When we have a string, it exists in a certain place in memory, and the bytes of the string cannot be made to go away.

Three ways to delete characters from a string are:

- Given the start address of the string, return the address of the desired part of the string.
- Given a pointer to the start of the string, update the pointer to point to the desired part of the string.
- Move characters from later in the string to earlier.

Here are sample implementations:

```
#include <stdio.h>


/*  Deletion method 0:  Find the first character that is not an "X" and
    return its address.
*/
static char *DeleteMethod0(char *string)
{
    for (char *p = string; ; ++p)
        if (*p != 'X')
            return p;
}


//  Deletion method 1:  Update the pointer to the start of the string.
static void DeleteMethod1(char **string)
{
    while (**string == 'X')
        ++*string;
}


//  Deletion method 2:  Move characters.
static void DeleteMethod2(char *string)
{
    //  Find the point where we stop deleting.
    char *source = string;
    while (*source == 'X')
        ++source;

    //  Copy the undeleted part of the string to the start.
    while (*source)
        *string++ = *source++;
    *string = '\0';
}


int main(void)
{
    char *string  = "XXXXXXXXXXXXTest";
    char buffer[] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXTest";

    printf("The string is %s.\n", string);
    printf("The buffer contains %s.\n", buffer);

    char *after = DeleteMethod0(string);
    printf("The string after deletion by getting new address %s.\n", after);

    DeleteMethod1(&string);
    printf("The string after deletion by updating the pointer is %s.\n", string);

    DeleteMethod2(buffer);
    printf("The buffer after deletion by moving characters is %s.\n", buffer);
}
```

Another option would be to make a new copy of the desired part of the string, in memory either supplied by the caller or allocated by the deletion routine.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function should be declared like

```
char * delChar( char *str );
```

The function parameter `str` is a local variable of the function. So this assignment

```
str = walker;
```

does not change the pointer `myStr` declared in main. This pointer is passed to the function by value. That is the function deals with a copy of the pointer. And the assignment does not change the original pointer `myStr`. It changes only its local variable `str` that was initialized by a copy of the value of the pointer `myStr`.

Also you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior. But you need indeed to change the passed string as at least followed from your assignment

> delete leading characters before a string in C

That is the task is not to find the pointer that points to the first character that is not equal to `'X'`. You need to remove leading characters equal to `'X'` from a string.

In main you need to declare a character array instead of a pointer to a string literal as for example

```
char myStr[] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXTest";
```

The function itself can be defined the following way

```
char * delChar( char *str )
{
    char *walker = str;

    while ( *walker == 'X' ) ++walker;

    if ( walker != str ) memmove( str, walker, strlen( str ) + 1 - ( walker - str ) );

    return str;
}
```

And in main it is enough to write

```
printf("After function call: %s\n", delChar( myStr ) );
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * delChar( char *str )
{
    char *walker = str;

    while (*walker == 'X') ++walker;

    if (walker != str) memmove( str, walker, strlen( str ) + 1 - ( walker - str ) );

    return str;
}

int main( void )
{
    char myStr[] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXTest";

    printf( "Before function call: %s\n", myStr );

    printf( "After function call: %s\n", delChar( myStr ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
Before function call: XXXXXXXXXXXXTest
After function call: Test
```

The function will be more flexible if to declare a second parameter that will specify a character that should be deleted from the beginning of a string. For example

```
char * delChar( char *str, char c )
{
    if ( c != '\0' )
    {
        char *walker = str;

        while (*walker == c) ++walker;

        if (walker != str) memmove( str, walker, strlen( str ) + 1 - ( walker - str ) );
    }

    return str;
}
```

In this case the function is called like

```
printf( "After function call: %s\n", delChar( myStr, 'X'));
```

Answer (score -1):

str variable in function `delChar` will created over stack and store address you have passed and will be destroyed when function returns

```
 void delChar(char* str)   // str variable will created over stack and store address you have passed and will be destroyed when function returns
{
    char* walker; //declare pointer
    walker = str;  //point to beginning of passed string
    
    while(*walker == 'X') walker++; //move pointer past amy leading 'X' 
   
    printf("\nwalker string is now: %s", walker); //prints "Test" as expected
    
    str = walker; //set str pointer to walker
    printf("\nstr string is now: %s", str); //prints "Test" as expected
    
    return;
}
```

After the return str in main will still point to start of the string.

**you need to return the address and store**

you can track count using counter and return the count Like below

```
#include<stdio.h>
int delChar(char* str)
{

int count = 0;

while(*str++ == 'X') 
    count++; // increment the count when x found 

printf("\nwalker string is now: %s", str+count); 
return count;
}


int main()
{
    char* myStr = "XXXXXXXXXXXXTest";
    int count;
    printf("Before function call: %s", myStr); 
    count = delChar(myStr);
    
    printf("\nAfter function call: %s", myStr+count);     
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the thoughtful replies and comments.  I infer that this has basically been a question about pointers; that is. modifying a string without needing to return a pointer from a function call. I simplified the example code question for the benefit of those who might be learning as well, with comments (see below).  Let me know if I’m off base here...

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    void func(char** str) //note POINTER-TO-POINTER parameter!
    {
        printf("\nintial func str: %s", *str); //note dereference before str; prints "FULL TEXT"
        *str += 5;  //increment pointer five spaces to right to modify the string
        printf("\nafter func str: %s", *str); //note dereference before str; prints "TEXT"
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        char* myStr = "FULL TEXT"; //need to initialize string with pointer variable
        //char myStr[] = "FULL TEXT"; //initializing string as array will not work for this example!
    
        printf("\n...before MAIN func call: %s", myStr); //prints "FULL TEXT"
    
        /*pass ADDRESS of pointer variable instead of pointer variable itself, i.e. func
        parameter needs to be a pointer-to-a-pointer...this is essentially passing by REFERENCE
        instead of by VALUE (where a copy would get clobbered when returning to main)*/
    
        func(&myStr); //note ADDRESS symbol, i.e. address of pointer variable
    
        printf("\n...after MAIN func call: %s", myStr); //prints "TEXT", modified string remains after func call
        return 0;
    }
```